# JTextField is too small/ can't seem to format it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I am trying to format these JTextFields, and they were working fine. Whenever I add the 4th and 5th rows however, the JTextfields become like 1 character long (like in the screenshot). I don't see any syntax errors or anything since the 1st through 3rd rows work fine on their own -- so I assume I'm just not aware of some limitation with the Layout Manager or something.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9fXs.jpg)

```
public PatientTab () {
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        ButtonGroup sexGroup = new ButtonGroup();
                sexGroup.add(maleRadioButton);
                sexGroup.add(femaleRadioButton);
        
        //row 1
        gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(new JLabel("First Name:"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(fName, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        add(new JLabel("Middle Initial:"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        add(mName, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        add(new JLabel("Last Name:"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        add(lName, gbc);
        
        // Row 2
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(new JLabel("Sex:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            add(maleRadioButton, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(femaleRadioButton, gbc);
        
            // Row 3
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
        add(new JLabel("SSN:"), gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(ssn, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        add(new JLabel("Primarary-care Doctor:"), gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        add(primaryDoctor, gbc);
        
        // Row 4
        gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 3;
        add(new JLabel("Secondary-care Doctor:"), gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        secondaryDoctor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,20));
        add(secondaryDoctor, gbc);
        
        
        // Row 5
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        add(new JLabel("Current Phone Number:"), gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(currentPhone, gbc);
        
        
        /*gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(addButton, gbc);*/
        
    }
```

Comment: *so I assume I'm just not aware of some limitation with the Layout Manager* - correct. When using a GridBagLayout is there is not enough spaces to display the component at its preferred size you will see this behaviour. It would appear you are using frame.setSize(...) to randomly set the size of the frame. Don't. Instead use frame.pack() after adding all the components.

Comment: `secondaryDoctor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,20));` - Also, don't manually set the preferred size. Each Swing component will determine its own preferred size.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it's needed to set size of frame or the panel. also method `pack()` could help:

```
 frame.pack();
 frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
```